# FullCalendar: How to stop dragging custom events?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Can anybody tell me how to stop dragging / resizing the events where `event.id > 100`? Only those events should be non draggable.

Updated with Code Sample:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if (event.id > 100) {
        event.disableDragging();
        event.disableResizing();
    }

    element.qtip({
        content: GetEventToolTip(event),
        position: { corner: { tooltip: 'bottomLeft', target: 'topMiddle'} },
        style: {
            border: {
                width: 1,
                radius: 5
            },
            padding: 5,
            textAlign: 'left',
            tip: false,
            name: event.iscustom == 'True' ? 'cream' : 'dark'
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `disableDragging` nor `disableResizing` are **functions** defined in fullcalendar as of 1.4.8.  I am certain that 2 people in the world haven't tried the first suggestion :)  Nevertheless, you'll need to tap into the jQuery UI object itself to disable dragging or resizing at the event level.  So (rather than trying to use non-existent functions) try this in your `eventRender(event, element)` callback:

```
if (event.id > 100) {

    element.draggable = false;

}
```

Note that I am simply setting the property on the jQuery element itself as it pertains to UI's draggable behavior.

The same goes for resizable EXCEPT that you will need to remove the div (`class = ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s`) that is appended by fullcalendar by identifying it with a jquery selector and removing it (just be sure to set a unique className per event in yoru events array so you can easily identify it in the `DOM`).  Please kindly petition the fullcalendar developer(s) to add `disableDragging` and `disableResizing` properties to the Event object.  It takes less than a minute to add support for this to the source.

Comment: @Saiful How do I go about disabling only resizable? I've trying adding         eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if (event.title == "typeA") 
            {       
             $('.typeA').resizable = false;
             
            }                       
        }, with no luck

Comment: In fullcalendar v2, property `editable` should be used instead of `draggable`

Answer (score 13):

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if (event.id.indexOf("IDENTIFYING_STRING") == -1) 
    {
        event.editable = false;
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Very good! I like this. Thanks. I still ended up removing the classes so that you don't get the mouse becoming a pointer and confusing the user. Other than that, the perfect solution. `$(element).find('.fc-resizer').remove();
$(element).removeClass('fc-draggable').removeClass('fc-resizable');`

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfect for me :

```
if ( event.id > 100 ) {
  element.draggable = false;
  element.resizable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    disableDragging = true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i would say:

```
if(event.id > 100)
{
   event.disableDragging();
   event.disableResizing();
}
```

Comment: +1: And, probably the best place to put this would be in the eventRender callback: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: It's not working, both method says: 
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 2):

**FullCalendar v1.6.4**

```
eventRender: function(jsEvent, element) {

 if(jsEvent.id > 100) {

    jsEvent.startEditable    = false;
    jsEvent.durationEditable = false;
  }

  return element;             
}
```

This solution has been working for me like a charm.

*I've implemented this JS library with Ruby Gem "Fullcalendar_engine".*

Answer (score 0):

You have to hack fullcalendar.js

uncomment lines

```
t.isEventDraggable = isEventDraggable;
t.isEventResizable = isEventResizable;
```

replace functions:

```
function isEventDraggable(event) {
         return isEventEditable(event) && !opt('disableDragging') &&
            !event.disableDragging;
}


function isEventResizable(event) { // but also need to make sure the seg.isEnd == true
         return isEventEditable(event) && !opt('disableResizing') &&
            !event.disableResizing; 
}
```

Now you can enable/disable resize and dragging for every event as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have success with the methods shown here. I ended up hacking fullcalendar.js to add a `noDragging` option for events, which was actually extremely easy:

original:

```
function isEventDraggable(event) {
    return isEventEditable(event) && !opt('disableDragging');
}
```

changed it to:

```
function isEventDraggable(event) {
    return isEventEditable(event) && !opt('disableDragging') && !event.noDragging;
}
```

Just added the check for `event.noDragging`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `element.draggable = false` and `event.ediable = false` worked for me. It must be because of the newer version of FullCalendar. If that's your case as well, try:

```
if ( event.id > 100 ) {
    event.startEditable = false;
}
```

Worked for me.

Alternatively you could cancel the move event after dropping:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

            if (event.id < 100) 
                revertFunc();
        }
```

Comment: revertFunc is not a function

Answer (score 0):

in editable just write false and it wont be able to drag and drop
                editable: false

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include more explanation that might help OP and anyone who might have the same problem in future

Answer (score -2):

Use these tags when creating your fullcalendar to disable dragging or resizing.

```
**>  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
> 
>    editable: false,
> 
> //the rest of your code... }**
```

Comment: This is for global disable, not for id > 100

Answer (score -4):

Use these tags when creating your fullcalendar to disable dragging or resizing. The arshaw docs aren't very explanatory but this is how to interpret them.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    disableResizing:true,
    disableDragging:true,

    //the rest of your code...
```

**disableDragging**: Boolean, *Default*: `false`
    Disables all event dragging, even when events are editable.

**disableResizing**: Boolean, *Default*: `false`
    Disables all event resizing, even when events are editable.